# Binding form inputs to Spring MVC model on an AJAX call

Tags: spring-mvc

My goal is to have a table where each row has the same 2 select lists. Then, I need an add button that will make an ajax call which will return the HTML for that table with a new row added. I'm using JQuery and Spring MVC.

Here's the file I render on the AJAX call:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="sec" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>



<table id = "reports" border = "1" class = "multisubmit">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Partner</th>
        <th>Permission Group</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="reportAccess" items="${request.reportAccessRowList}" varStatus="loop">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:select path = "request.reportAccessRowList[${loop.index}].partnerId">
                    <option value = "par1">Partner 1</option>
                    <option value = "par2">Partner 2</option>
                </form:select>

            </td>
            <td>
                <form:select   path = "request.reportAccessRowList[${loop.index}].permissionId">
                    <option value = "permission1">Permission1</option>
                    <option value = "permission2">Permission2</option>
                </form:select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class = "rdelete" type = "button" onclick = "deleteRow(${loop.index})">
                    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
                    Delete
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the javascript code for the 'add row' button:

```html
function addRow()
{
    var formData = $("#reportForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url : "addReport/addRow",
        data:formData,
        dataType: "html",
        type: "post",
        success : function(data) {
            $("#reports").html(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Here's the controller code:

```html
 private void addStubRow()
 {
    ReportAccessRow stub = new ReportAccessRow();
    stub.getAvailablePermissionNames().add("permission1");
    stub.getAvailablePermissionIds().add("0");
    stub.getAvailablePermissionNames().add("permission2");
    stub.getAvailablePermissionIds().add("1");
    stub.setPartnerId("0");
    stub.setPermissionId( "0" );
    this.request.getReportAccessRowList().add(stub);
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/addRow", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String addRow(  Model model )
{
    //this.request = newRequest;
    addStubRow(); 
    model.addAttribute("request", request);
    return "admin.event.reports.requests"; //this identifies the JSP page that renders the table
}
```

The ajax call goes through and re-renders the table. However, I always loose any selections I've made because the table re-renders itself without saving any of the input data.  I'm a little new to this version of spring so I don't quite understand how to connect the inputs to the data model in a consistent fashion.

Comment: Is it an option to simply a new row without re-rendering the whole table? This can be done on the client. Or is submitting the existing data a requirement.

Comment: I might try it that way.